# Importing co-ordinates from excel to Autodesk Inventor via VBA

Tags: excel, import, coordinates, autodesk-inventor

The overall aim of the code is to be able to generate a model pipe within Autodesk Inventor, via the sweep function, from a selection of nodal co-ordinates in Microsoft Access, which have been imported into Excel so Excel acts as a "middle-man". In other words, trying to connect Excel to Inventor to import co-ordinates from Excel.

The existing code I have created will generate a pipe from nodal coordinates and bend values manually typed into VBA by hand.

I have had numerous attempts at trying to connect Excel to Inventor with no success. The most promising of which I have shown below, which is aiming to select an excel file though my attempt at extracting the value from cell A5 and insert it into my manually imputed coordinates doesn't work.

Other methods I have tried include Import Points (where it turns out API does not support this) and manipulating the code in the following link:

https://reinventinginventor.wordpress.com/vba-code-for-exporting-inventor-parts-list-to-excel-with-thumbnails/

But, to no avail.

```
'Set up 3D sketch
Dim Sketch2 As Sketch3D
Set Sketch2 = partDef.Sketches3D.Add


'Identify File address path
Dim Path1 As String
Path1 = InputBox("Enter Excel file Path e.g         C:\SapWorkDir\Inventor\UpdateOpen.xlsx", "Excel file Path")


' Get the Excel file
Dim Excel As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As WorkSheet
Set Excel = New Excel.Application'Set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Path1)
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

Dim Test As Integer
Test = ws.Range("A5").Select





'input coordinate values (CURRENTLY MANUAL)
Dim oCoor(1 To 8) As WorkPoint
Set oCoor(1) = partDef.WorkPoints.AddFixed(tg.CreatePoint(0, 0, 0))
Set oCoor(2) = partDef.WorkPoints.AddFixed(tg.CreatePoint(100, 100, 0))
Set oCoor(3) = partDef.WorkPoints.AddFixed(tg.CreatePoint(100, 50, 30))
Set oCoor(4) = partDef.WorkPoints.AddFixed(tg.CreatePoint(200, 700, 30))
Set oCoor(5) = partDef.WorkPoints.AddFixed(tg.CreatePoint(600, 700, 70))
Set oCoor(6) = partDef.WorkPoints.AddFixed(tg.CreatePoint(600, 700, 500))
Set oCoor(7) = partDef.WorkPoints.AddFixed(tg.CreatePoint(600, 900, 500))
Set oCoor(8) = partDef.WorkPoints.AddFixed(tg.CreatePoint(600, 2000, 500))
'
```

This method is clearly not working as I cannot call up the value "A5" into any of my manually typed in co-ordinate values.

I assume I am unable to connect to Excel via this method, so does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the Excel library into Inventor's VBA to make VBA aware of Excel and it's API.  Use the "References..." command in the Tools menu and select the checkbox beside "Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library" from the list, as shown below.

[image: Referencing the Excel library]

You can now use code like what's shown below to access Excel and then use its full API to extract the values from cells.  I like the Cells method where I can easily specify the row and column.

```
Public Sub ConnectToExcel()
    ' Connect to Excel
    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
    Set excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    ' Run this line if you want to see Excel.  By default it is invisible.
    ' excelApp.Visible = True

    ' Open the workbook.
    Dim workBook As workBook
    Set workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Test.xlsx")

    ' Get the sheet.
    Dim sheet As WorkSheet
    Set sheet = workBook.Sheets.Item("Sizes")

    ' Get some values.
    Dim val1 As String
    val1 = sheet.Cells(1, 1)
    Dim val2 As String
    val2 = sheet.Cells(1, 2)

    ' Close it down.
    excelApp.Quit
End Sub
```